# How to prevent a list inside a function changing the list outside the function?

Tags: python, list

I was using a 2D list and ran into an issue. The changes I made to my list in the function was being applied to the list outside the function. I need to be able to edit the list inside the function, but I want to keep the original list.

```
def function(lst2):
    lst2[0][2] += 5

lst1 = [[9, 6, 4], [6, 8, 3]]
function(lst1)
print(lst1)
```

This is the output:

```
[[9, 6, 9], [6, 8, 3]]
```

I tried a few stuff and found that doing this works:

```
def function(lst3):
    lst3[0][2] += 5
    print(lst3)

lst1 = [[9, 6, 4], [6, 8, 3]]
lst2 = []
for i in lst1:
    lst2.append(i[:])
function(lst2)
print(lst1)
```

However, I'm working with a pretty big matrix and I need to use the function many times, so repeatedly looping through the matrix seems very inefficient.

I'm pretty sure there are much more elegant solutions I don't know about. I'm also curious about why this happens when other variables are local to functions.

Comment: _The changes I made to my list in the function was being applied to the list outside the function_ That's because they both refer to **the same object**.

Comment: There **is only one list**. "so repeatedly looping through the matrix seems very inefficient." There is fundamentally no other choice. You cannot have your cake and eat it too. in this case, you want *a new list*, so you *have to create that list*. You can't have it be the same list, and not the same list, at the same time. "I'm pretty sure there are much more elegant solutions I don't know about" yuo could copy the list using `copy.deepcopy`, although, that will probably be *slower*,  although the most elegant. Or you could use a list comprehension, which will be only be slightly faster.

Comment: But in the end, you can't get around copying the list, since *that is what you want*: a copy.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def function(lst2):
    lst2[0][2] += 5

lst1 = [[9, 6, 4], [6, 8, 3]]
function(lst1)
print(lst1)
```

When you call `function(lst1)` you are passing the `lst1` object to the function

```py
def function(lst2):
    # change the object 
    lst2[0][2] += 5
```

##### how to not pass an object but return a new object

```py
def function(lst2):
    # make a copy of the list so that the original list is not changed
    new_list = [list(i) for i in lst2]
    new_list[0][2] += 5
    return new_list


lst1 = [[9, 6, 4], [6, 8, 3]]
my_new_list = function(lst1)
print("list 1", lst1)
print("list 2", my_new_list)
```

#### Personally I would do it like this using deep copy

```
import copy

ORIGINAL = [[9, 6, 4], [6, 8, 3]]
def get_new_copy():
   
    copied_list = copy.deepcopy(ORIGINAL)
    return copied_list


def add_five(lst):
    lst[0][2] += 5


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = get_new_copy()  # I want to get a copy of original list

    add_five(my_list)  # I want to add 5 to the last element of the first list
    print(my_list)  # I want to print modified list

    print(ORIGINAL )  # I want to print original list
```

Comment: `new_list = lst2[0][2] + 5` that is not a list. That is an `int`

Comment: your `get_new_copy` function, which defines `ORIGINAL = [[9, 6, 4], [6, 8, 3]]` at the top, **pointlessly uses `copy.deepcopy(ORIGINAL)`**